# Returning Javascript include from Server-side - Unterminated String Literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to update an HTML element with a JS snippet returned from a server-side method.

```
 return MvcHtmlString.Create(@"<script type='text/javascript' src='//static.atgsvcs.com/js/atgsvcs.js'></script>
                                        <script type='text/javascript'>  ATGSvcs.setUOID(111111); </script>
                                        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://as00.estara.com/as/InitiateCall2.php?accountid=111111'></script>");
```

I then try to update a div with the returned JS.

```
    LoadChatScript: function (chatScript) {
        $jq('#metachatscript').replaceWith(chatScript)
}
```

However, I keep getting an 'Unterminated string literal' error. Do I need to sanitize the JS somehow?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the html you are returning, however replacewith doesn't seem like the right tool for the job here.

Comment: i would just append the script files rather then replace.

Comment: There is a method call between the two JS references and I think it has to happen in that order.